# I want a function that check whether or not the input is an int and also if it's in the required range or not in python

Tags: python

Here is my code which runs but is broken, seems like the if statement isn't working and no matter what user has entered, it keeps asking to enter again

```
b = True

while b:
    a = input('numtber: ')
    try:
        int(a)
    except:
        continue
    else:
        if a in range(0,100):
            a = int(a)
            b = False
            break
            
    continue
```

Comment: `a` is still a string, so `a in range(0,100)` can never evaluate to true.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I find it interesting that it does not raise a TypeError, given that `range.__contains__` supposedly uses math to do the `in` check. Perhaps it returns `False` early if the type is not an `int`. I'll check the C code later

Comment: @DeepSpace there's a special case that's checked numerically, otherwise it falls back to iterating search: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47feb1feb28631b6647699b7633109aa85340966/Objects/rangeobject.c#L427-L435

Comment: @jonrsharpe nice, thanks. Is there any way to get that to return `True`? `range` objects can only be created with numeric values, and they can be indexed into but are not assignable

Comment: @DeepSpace you might have `some_instance in range(...)`, then it comes down to your `__eq__`.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your code like this:

```
b = True

while b:   
    try:
        a = int(input('numtber: '))
    except:
        continue
    else:
        if a in range(0,100):
            a = int(a)
            b = False
            break
            
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to transform the integer exactly after the user types a number. Also, you can wrap try except around the input.

```
 b = True

while b:
    try:
        a = int(input("Insert your number: "))
        if a in range(0, 100):
            print(f"{a} is in the [0, 100) range")
        else:
            print(f"{a} is outside the [0, 100) range")
            b = False
    except:
        print("Please insert an integer")
        continue
```

I hope this approach is what you've been looking for.